# Prove that an ideal is not maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Ring $\mathbb Z[x],$ ideal is $(x)$. How to prove that this is NOT a maximal ideal?

I can't imagine ideal, part of which would be $(x)$.

Comment: How about this: $I=(x)+(2)$?

Comment: How can you add ideals?

Comment: Hint: What'd be the inverse of $\;2+\langle x\rangle\in\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x\rangle\;$ ?

Comment: @DarkArchon How can you *not*? Sum of ideals is well defined *and* an ideal again!

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb Z$ is not a field, the ideal $(x)$ can't be maximal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ideal $(x, 2)$ of $\Bbb Z[x]$. $(x, 2)$ is a proper ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$ since $3 \notin (x, 2)$. Hence $(x) \subset (x, 2) \subset \Bbb Z[x]$, implying $(x)$ is not maximal.

Answer (score 5):

If it was maximal then $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x)$ would be a field. So every non zero element has to have multiplicative inverse. $2 + (x)$ is not the zero element so there should be $f + (x)$ such that $(2 + (x))(f + (x)) = 1 + (x)$. So $2f - 1 \in (x)$, which means that if the constant term of $f$ is $a$, then $2a - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow a = \frac{1}{2}$. And this is a contradicton since $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Technically you can't write $a=\frac12$. It's better to conclude by saying that for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $2a-1\neq0$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Technically there is nothing wrong with solving an equation in a larger system, like $\mathbf Q$, to see the solution is not an integer and thus there is no integral solution. For example, if I wanted to show $3+4i$ is not divisible by $1+2i$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$, it is perfectly fine to work in $\mathbf Q(i)$ and compute the ratio $(3+4i)/(1+2i) = (11-2i)/5 = 11/5-(2/5)i$, which is not in $\mathbf Z[i]$.

Comment: @KCd yeah but you then have to mention you're working in a larger space. Though here, the set of rationals is so common that everybody takes it for granted, but if we were to work in fancier spaces, this kind of argument would make proofs uselessly difficult (and even sometimes impossible); it's a good idea to be aware of optimal arguments sometimes.

Comment: @KCd Regarding your example: assume there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $(3+4i)=a(1+2i)$. Then (multiplying by $1-2i$) we must have: $11-2i=5a$, which is impossible. There's no reason to use $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ at all here.

Comment: When using this argument, wouldn't it just be easier to say "$\Bbb Z[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb Z$ which is clearly not a field."?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: there is nothing wrong with working in $\mathbf Q$ to look at questions about $\mathbf Z$ or in $\mathbf Q(i)$ to look at questions in $\mathbf Z[i]$. Even if you prefer for reasons of "purity of method" to study a problem without using anything outside the context of the original problem, others may find it simpler to think about things in a different way. Saying $1/2 \not\in \mathbf Z$ is the same as saying $2a-1 \not= 0$ for all $a \in \mathbf Z$, but some people find the first way of speaking more appealing.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the universal property of the polynomial ring is as follows:

> for any ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$ and any element $s\in S$, there exists one and only one ring homomorphism $f_s\colon R[x]\to S$ such that $f_s(r)=f(r)$, for all $r\in R$, and $f_s(x)=s$.

Specialize this to $R=S$, $s=0$, $f$ the identity. Then
$$
\ker f_0=(x)
$$
because $f_0(x)=0$ by definition, so $(x)\subseteq\ker f_0$; if $p\in R[x]$, write $p(x)=a+xq(x)$, where $a\in R$. Then $f_0(p)=a$, so $p\in\ker f_0$ implies $a=0$ and so $p\in(x)$.

Thus $\ker f_0=(x)$ and so, by the homomorphism theorem,
$$
R[x]/(x)\cong R
$$
Therefore $(x)$ is maximal in $R[x]$ if and only if $R$ is a field.